# cmake error when building a C library as BPF

Tags: cmake, compilation, bpf

I would like to use a rust library that is a C bindings in Solana.
First Solana is calling the `cmake` of the h3 library, I am replicating the process here.
I am cloning the repo and creating a build folder

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/nmandery/h3ron.git
mkdir h3ron/build
cd h3ron/build
```

I export the path to lld and run the cmake command very similar to solana's command (I added `-v -fuse-ld=lld` ) why is solana missing this one argument? it seems it needs solana's `lld` and not the system `ld`.

```
export PATH="/home/pc/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.4/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/:$PATH"

"cmake" "../h3ron-h3-sys/libh3" \
"-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./h3ron-h3-sys-df478ba73015eab9/out" \
"-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=bpfel-unknown-none -v -fuse-ld=lld" \
"-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/pc/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.4/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/clang" \
"-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -v" \
"-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++" \
"-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=bpfel-unknown-unknown -v" \
"-DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/home/pc/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.4/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/clang" \
"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
```

The error:

```
Target: bpfel-unknown-none
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/pc/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.4/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin
"/usr/bin/gcc" -fuse-ld=lld -rdynamic -o cmTC_26933 CMakeFiles/cmTC_26933.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
ld.lld: error: CMakeFiles/cmTC_26933.dir/testCCompiler.c.o is incompatible with elf64-x86-64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note: The system ld would generate this error `/usr/bin/ld: unknown architecture of input file CMakeFiles/cmTC_5c450.dir/testCCompiler.c.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output`

any idea?